# Biztalk Creating RESTful WCF service by exposing the schema

Tags: wcf, rest, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I need to create the RESTful WCF service for the schema I have in the application. The schema which has three elements

[image]

My requirement is to create the WCF service so I can pass these three values through the service. Can anybody give me clear idea how can I approach this. I have been trying to create a schema, and promoted the one of the element for example the user name and created the property schema like 
[image]

I deployed this and tried creating the WCf service through the publishing wizard selecting WCF WebHTTp adapter(which didnt ask we to select the schema) created the service and configured the application in Biztalk console. But the service is not working. If I call the service with the parameters , still it shows the 
[image]
Can anybody please help me how can I approach this. I am really stuck with this for long time. Please any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What service url you are using to test the service?

Comment: @VikasBhardwaj  **http://localhost/Demo/Service1.svc?username='abc'&password='def'&specimenid=J000123** am trying like this

Comment: @VikasBhardwaj I went through your blog [link](http://vikasbhardwaj15.blogspot.com/2014/01/publish-rest-service-from-biztalk-server.html) and followed the same steps but I am not sure what I am missing

Comment: You are missing the operation name in url, add that to the url after .svc/, and then try again

Comment: I have doubt, while creating the service using the wizard it was not asking for operation. So n Receive Location I just gave **Operation Name="Op1" Method = "GET" Url ="/specimen={specimen}** (i just gave specimenid because i created a new application just promoting specimenid) and trying passing only that and test. So the URL ** "http://localhost/Demo/Service1.svc/Op1?specimen=J000123"** I get **" AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree"** I am new to creating services through biztalk. Not sure wat does the error mean.

Comment: Is it possible to get the MSI of the application you created in the blog for Publish REST Service from BizTalk Server

Comment: This error means that Server is not able to find out the action it needs to do based upon the URL and request. Based on your configuration on receive location, your url should localhost/demp/service1.svc/specimenid=value, if that does not work then in my blog, I have used status/{airportcode}, try to use it in same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that Server is not able to find out the action it needs to do based upon the URL and request. Based on your configuration on receive location, your url should be localhost/demp/service1.svc/specimen=value, if that does not work then, change the Operation Name="Op1" Method = "GET" Url ="specimen/{specimen} and then your url should be localhost/demp/service1.svc/specimen/value

Comment: If I am having two or more parameters how will I give that in HTTP method in the Receive location.

Comment: You can add more parameters same way separating them by /, however, another approach is to use complex type structure such as XML which you can receive as part of a HTTP body. This is a separate topic though. If yr URL problem is solved make this as answered and open a new thread

Comment: when I give like below http://localhost/Demo/Service1.svc/value/J000123134 the browser keeps loading for hours together. I cannot see anything.

Comment: Can you please share the msi of the appplication in the blog. I think I am missing something.